# Vertical Bootstrap nav (rotated -90°)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-4

How to create a [Bootstrap Nav](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navs/) with vertically aligned items like so:

[image]

I'm **not** trying to design a stacked layout with horizontally aligned items one below each other.

I tried to add `transform:rotate(-90deg);` to `.list-group-item`, however, it looks like rotational transformation is applied after elements are aligned on the page, and therefore I would have to position each element manually using JavaScript. I'm looking for a clean CSS-only solution, possibly without any "hackarounds".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(edit) My 1st answer using **`writing-mode: vertical-lr`** and then **`transform: rotate(180deg);`** plus some CSS to make it work or as a starter (no, flex isn't needed here but I use it so much for navbars...)

**[Codepen](http://codepen.io/PhilippeVay/pen/VKxyvg)**: clearer than snippet below because I could use Autoprefixer (and also Normalize and LESS which is used by Bootstrap 3 but you can use Sass here - if you already use Bootstrap 4 alpha - syntax is identical for both here)

If you don't use Autoprefixer, then result is:

```css
.nav-tabs {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
    -ms-flex-flow: column nowrap;
        flex-flow: column nowrap;
    -webkit-box-align: start;
        -ms-flex-align: start;
            align-items: flex-start;
  }
.nav-tabs > li {
    -webkit-writing-mode: vertical-lr;
        -ms-writing-mode: tb-lr;
            writing-mode: vertical-lr;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
            transform: rotate(180deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: center center;
            transform-origin: center center;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.nav-tabs > li > a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.6rem 1rem;
  background-color: beige;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
</ul>
```

I didn't include existing CSS from Bootstrap for this component so you'll have to override a bunch of declarations but I at least used the same selectors like `*** > li > a` and copy-pasted HTML from documentation.

My reasoning is that rotating by +/- 90ddeg is never *safe*. Width becomes height, height becomes width and it's messy because content is so fluid. So I wrote text vertically with [writing-mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode) and then had to rotate by half a turn text to mimick your design. Doing so doesn't change dimensions of each element so no bad surprise ;)

Comment: Great idea using the `writing-mode` property!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are correct in using `transform:rotate(-90deg);` but I would apply it to the wrapper to all of the list items whether it be the `<ul>` or the next level up. That should rotate everything as one unit.

Comment: No, that would put Item2 to the right of Item 1 instead of the bottom. See https://snag.gy/rqBoOA.jpg

Answer (score 0):

My 2nd answer, using Flexbox positioning this time and then some `transform`ations

**[Codepen](http://codepen.io/PhilippeVay/pen/RGyxvA)**

```css
.nav-tabs {
  display: -webkit-inline-box;
  display: -ms-inline-flexbox;
  display: inline-flex;
    -ms-flex-flow: row-reverse nowrap;
        flex-flow: row-reverse nowrap;
    -webkit-box-pack: end;
        -ms-flex-pack: end;
            justify-content: flex-end;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(-100%);
          transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(-100%);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
          transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  padding-left: 0;
}
.nav-tabs > li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
.nav-tabs > li  > a {
  display: block;
  padding: 9.6px 16px;
  padding: 0.6rem 1rem;
  background-color: beige;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
</ul>
```

Items are displayed from right to left horizontally with `flex-direction: row-reverse` with the idea of doing `transform: rotate(-90deg)` a while after. But doing so on a wide flex container wouldn't work, so I used `inline-flex`: navbar is close to its final position.
Then taking care of `transform-origin`, rotating and adjusting position with `translateX()` to move… *vertically* (due to previous rotation, it's a bit confusing)

EDIT: [CSS-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) is the best summary when it comes to Flexbox.